# Adjusting width of column to fit text onto page in GridView AutoGenerateColumn

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem trying to adjust the columns or cells of each row to make it so that the text does not span too horizontally or vertically as it is currently:

[image: Text Problem]

As you can see in the photo, the text under the `"Summary"` column is too long and makes the page too wide so users have to scroll to see the other columns. I have tried multiple ways to adjust the width of the cell so the text would be confined but I cannot seemingly get it to work. I have tried the following in my code:

```
e.Row.Cells[3].Wrap = false;  //Works but makes it so text spans horizontally as opposed to vertically
e.Row.Cells[3].Attributes.Add("style", "word-wrap:break-word;"); //Does not work
e.Row.Cells[3].Width = new Unit("50px"); //Does not work
```

The only one I could get working is adjusting the wrap attribute to be false but doing so makes the text span too wide. If I leave it to true, I get the problem with the text under the `"Quick_Sum"` column where the text spans too vertically and thus makes every cell unnecessarily large. I would like to fix both of them so that it would make the GridView look nice.

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;


public partial class Maintenance : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ProductSetTableAdapters.Product_Table_AlphaTableAdapter productAdapter = new ProductSetTableAdapters.Product_Table_AlphaTableAdapter();
            ProductView.DataSource = productAdapter.GetData();
            ProductView.DataBind();
        }

        ProductView.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(ProductViewRowBound);
    }

    protected void ProductViewRowBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string hyperLink = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "";
            string id = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
            string navigationURL = "Product_Maintenance.aspx?product=" + id;
            HyperLink link = new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = navigationURL, Text=hyperLink };
            e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(link);

        e.Row.Cells[3].Wrap = false;  //Works but makes it so text spans horizontally as opposed to vertically
        e.Row.Cells[3].Attributes.Add("style", "word-wrap:break-word;"); //Does not work
        e.Row.Cells[3].Attributes.Add("style", "white-space:normal;"); //Does not work - Acts the same as if wrap was true
        e.Row.Cells[3].Width = new Unit("500px"); //Does not work
        e.Row.Cells[2].Width = new Unit("500px"); //Does not work

        ProductView.Columns[3].ItemStyle.Width = 50; //Throws ArgumentOutOfRange exception
        }
    }
}
```

ASPX Code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Maintenance.aspx.cs" Inherits="Maintenance" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
        <asp:GridView ID="ProductView" runat="server" Height="299px" Width="863px" AllowPaging="True" HorizontalAlign="Center"
            OnRowDataBound="ProductViewRowBound">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I am using a `TableAdapter` to communicate with my SQL Server 2017 express database. Also, I am using Auto-Generated Columns and to my knowledge, I cannot specify the style until they are created. How do I format the columns so that the text can fit nicely in both `"Quick_Sum"` and `"Summary"` from behind the code?

**EDIT** - Tried some of the solutions and updated the code to reflect on that and what each resulted in accordingly.

**EDIT 2** - Tried wazz's solution and it worked. Removing the set dimensions of the GridView in the aspx file made it so that the hard-coded width adjustments in the RowDataBound method make noticeable changes.

**Updated C# Code:**

```
protected void ProductViewRowBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string hyperLink = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "";
        string id = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        string navigationURL = "Product_Maintenance.aspx?product=" + id;
        HyperLink link = new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = navigationURL, Text=hyperLink };
        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(link);

        e.Row.Cells[3].Wrap = false; 
        e.Row.Cells[3].Attributes.Add("style", "white-space:normal;"); //Removing this strangely makes it so that it looks like when wrap is on
        e.Row.Cells[3].Width = new Unit("500px"); //Now works
        e.Row.Cells[2].Width = new Unit("500px"); //Now works

    }
}
```

**Updated ASPX:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Maintenance.aspx.cs" Inherits="Maintenance" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
        <asp:GridView ID="ProductView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" HorizontalAlign="Center"
            OnRowDataBound="ProductViewRowBound" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

[image: Updated GridView with the fix]

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You're hard-coding these widths in your markup?

Comment: @IrishChieftain Yeah I hard-coded the widths within the RowDataBound method since as far as I know, that is the way to do it since I am using AutoGeneratedColumns. Is there a different way to do so or perhaps I hard-coded the widths incorrectly?

Comment: Not in the RowDataBound method, in the markup.

Comment: @IrishChieftain Do you mean in the aspx? I am unfamiliar with that term but if you mean in the aspx, then no since I have set my GridView to automatically generate columns when I bind the data using the TableAdapter.

Comment: Change  Height="299px" Width="863px" to 581px each and see what happens?

Comment: @IrishChieftain I changed the heights and width to 581px each and I didn't see any visible changes. On the design view, I noticed that the gridview itself was different (it was a bit taller and less wide) but besides that, the texts in the "Quick_Sum" and "Summary" still have the same issues as in the picture above.

Comment: Look into ItemTemplates and setting the sizes in the asp.

Comment: Can you add bootstrap?

Comment: Maybe if you hard-code `white-space: normal` (instead of word-wrap). (?) Also try hard-coding a width for both columns 2 and 3. (In RowBound.)

Comment: @wazz Made the change to white-space:normal and it made the "Summary" column act as if "wrap" was on. Adding "nowrap" instead leads to the same result as the picture above. Additionally, I tried hard-coding a width for both columns 2 and 3 and there seems to be no notable changes. Even when I changed the values to 500 for each, there were no visible changes.

Comment: Have you tried removing the width completely from the gridview? I think it might be forcing the columns to do strange things just to fit the width. Try removing everything to start with.

Comment: @wazz That seems to have worked. You're probably right on that with a set height and width, the GridView does weird things to the columns to fit the dimensions. Removing the height and width made the hard-coded width adjustments in the RowDataBound make noticeable changes. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Mention the GridView name at first `GridView1.SomeProperties...` and in RowDataBound event:

> - Set the **Width** property for the `ItemStyle` property.
> - Set the **Wrap** property of the `ItemStyle` property to *FALSE*.
>
>   If the **Wrap** property is *FALSE*, the column is automatically resized.

```
GridView1.Columns[2].ItemStyle.Width = 50;
GridView1.Columns[2].ItemStyle.Wrap = false;
```

Following the MSDN: [How to: Set GridView Web Server Control Column Width Dynamically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178296.aspx)

Comment: I tried this and it's throwing a ArgumentOutOfRangeException. I don't understand why it is throwing this exception.

Comment: Probably, you have entered invalid column number.

Comment: I tried using ProductView.Columns[0] and it also threw the same error. I think this is because I technically do not have any columns with the way I setup my GridView. I'll try rebuilding my GridView so that it uses TemplateFields and then try your solution again.